# How to update database file over internet?

Tags: objective-c, database

My App has a database file in its NSBundle. I want to get update database file from internet whenever new database file is available. and this should happen before app displays data from the database file.
Here is the logic i am trying to use. i don't know if it makes sense or is there a better way to do it. an example will be awesome

```
if (file is available in the Documents Directory)
{
    if( check if internet is available )
    {
        1. get file from network
        2. store it in Documents Directory
        if ( compare contents of the old & new file)
        {
            delete downloaded file
        } else {
            move or delete old file & rename new file ( so that the new file's data can be accessed )
        }
    } else {
        use old file in Documents Directory
    }
} else {
    copy file from bundle to Documents Directory
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you should have a timestamp or version number for the copy of the DB you have on the phone, and transmit that to the server.  Then have the server only send a new copy if there is a newer version.  Saves the user a lot of data charges.

Comment: Agreed.  Don't transmit the entire DB.  You may also want to read up on database version control. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/02/get-your-database-under-version-control.html

Comment: Hot Licks & DougW, Thanks for guiding. Can you please point me to some tutorial link or a sample code that can help me with it.

Comment: @Hitz -- Generally speaking, you should use a REST interface.  Once you can interact with a REST interface then the details are fairly simple (or more complicated, if you want to do partial updates -- that's up to you).

Comment: @Hot Licks - How do I do all that. Not much familiar with all these stuffs. This is my first App. If you can write me a sample code or tuts it would be a great help. Thanks

Comment: Well, I'd suggest you study up on REST, and learn how to interact with a REST interface (and also how to implement one on the server side).  Ya gotta crawl before you walk.

Comment: @HotLicks - Thanks for your help. At least now I know how you can make things better. I'll sure learn REST and other things around sql database. Going throught some SQL books. Thanks again